# Resultados do INNER JOIN na Horizontal

Tags: join, inner

Tenho certeza que é algo simples, mas não estou conseguindo: darei o exemplo.

tb_empresa e tb_contatosdaempresa

Cada empresa possui até 8 contatos (Campos: id_empresa / nome / telefone / email)

Preciso fazer um inner join de uma forma que para cada empresa retornada (tb_empresa) apareçam todos os contatos e seus respectivos dados, porém na vertical, em forma de colunas, para depois exportar para o Excel !!! Tipo:

Linha01 >> Nome da Empresa | Nome Contato 01 | Telefone Contato 01 | Email Contato 01 | Nome Contato 02 | Telefone Contato 02 | Email Contato 02...

Linha02 >> Nome da Empresa | Nome Contato 01 | Telefone Contato 01 | Email Contato 01 | Nome Contato 02 | Telefone Contato 02 | Email Contato 02... Assim

Linha03 >> Nome da Empresa | Nome Contato 01 | Telefone Contato 01 | Email Contato 01 | Nome Contato 02 | Telefone Contato 02 | Email Contato 02... Assim

Assim consectivamente até o oitavo contato, mesmo que não chege a ter 8 contatos cadastrados para essa empresa (No caso fica em branco). Pois da forma que estpou fazendo, é criado uma linha para cada contato que a empresa tem, repetindo o nome da empresa várias vezes.

Podem me dar um help ???

Comment: Dependendo do SGBD utilizado existem ferramentas para isso. No PostgreSQL a função crosstab de tablefunc pode ajuda-lo. Outros SGBD implementam a feature pivot.

Comment: Acredito que seja esse o caminho. Vou estudar esse feature pois trata-se de MySQL. Vlws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer o select assim:

```
 SELECT e.*,
( 
  SELECT ',' + ContatoNome AS 'data()' 
         FROM #Contato where idEmpresa = e.Id FOR XML PATH('')
) as contatos
FROM #Empresa as e
```

Utilize [este site](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1089759/teste-converter-linhas-para-string) para testar.

**EDITADO**
Estava dando uma olhada na documentação da função pivot mas acho que ela também não vai lhe atender.
Como seu objetivo é exportar para o Excel eu imagino que você estaria exportando o resultado desse select para um arquivo CSV certo?
Se for isso a idéia para resolver seu problema seria criar um select trazendo tudo em uma única coluna e cada já separado por virgula (ou o charactere que você achar melhor).
Segue abaixo o exemplo:

```
select ' NomeEmpresa,Contato1,emailcontato1,Contato2,emailcontato2' as 'ignorar' union all
 select e.EmpresaNome+','+
( 
  SELECT ContatoNome +','+ContatoEmail+',' AS 'data()' 
         FROM #Contato where idEmpresa = e.Id FOR XML PATH('')
         )
from #Empresa as e
```

O importante aqui é o primeiro select que vai conter o cabeçalho dos seus campos e logo depois os dados da tabela.
Depois de gerar o arquivo CSV, abra o mesmo no excel, apague a primeira linha com o nome 'ignorar' e pronto.
Teste o exemplo acima [neste site](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1089783/teste-csv) aqui você consegue exportar para CSV também.

Comment: Murilo, muito obrigado antes de qqr coisa. Nesse exemplo que vc passou eu vi dois pontos: O primeiro é que somente um campo (Nome) está sendo trazido e o segundo é que ambos os contatos estão na mesma "celula". Oq preciso é que todas as informações de contatos sejam trazidas e cada uma em uma coluna, até virem os dados do segundo contato. O caminho continua sendo esse que vc passou ouu muda muito ???

Comment: @NaimarNunes Editei minha resposta com um novo código, como seu objetivo é exportar para o excel fazendo do jeito que falei da certo, só precisa apagar a primeira linha do arquivo CSV. No final da resposta tem o site onde criei o código, pode utiliza-lo para testar e criar o arquivo csv também.

Comment: Murilo Portugal, Essa resposta foi perfeita e sim, é exatamente isso que preciso. Já brinquei com o codigo para entender bem a lógica dele e vou aplicar essa semana. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: @NaimarNunes fico feliz em poder lhe ajudar. Se a reposta atende o seu problema, por favor considera marca-la como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.